# Как задать ширину, отталкиваясь от кол-ва текста в блоке?

Tags: css, sass

Есть ли в CSS величины, которые отталкиваются от кол-ва текста в блоке? Например, *"на 50px больше, чем занимает текст в блоке"* или *"в 3 раза больше, чем этот блок с текстом"*. Или может в SASS есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SASS компилируется в CSS, кроме более продвинутого синтаксиса в нем нет преимуществ.

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность отталкиваться от текста в блоке, вам поможет вариант отображения `display: inline-block`.

Ваш первый пример можно решить так:

```css
.demo {
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  +50px
</div>

<div class="demo">
  Long Long Long Text +50px
</div>
```

Второй пример не достаточно понятен, чтобы привести какое-то решение, возможно что  в вашей ситуации нельзя обойтись только лишь css.